# AVCaptureScreenInput and kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, avfoundation

I am doing screen capture with AVCaptureScreenInput. The app has a window with configuration options.

I want to record the screen but not record the window in the recorder application. Quicktime does this if you do a screen recording, as an example.

I think I found what will do it, but I'm not sure how or if they can be used together.

kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow is found in CGWindow.h in the Core Graphics framework. AVCaptureScreenInput is part of AVCaptureInput.h in the AVFoundation framework.

If you are taking a single screenshot, you can pass kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow and a windowID so that only windows below that window's level are captured. I can accomplish my goal by setting the capture app's window to a very high level if this works.

I'm relatively new to Objective-c ands its not clear to me if its possible to use the kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenBelowWindow with AVCaptureScreenInput. If it is, could someone provide tips on what the resulting code needs to look like?

[How to access the pixel buffer of an NSWindow in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458308/how-to-access-the-pixel-buffer-of-an-nswindow-in-osx)

Comment: i have to implement such a feature if you have any idea about this then please tell me also thanks @Geuis

Comment: @iMac I haven't followed up with this project since August and never got as far as implementing this. I was waiting for 10.9 to come out to see if new API's would make this easier. I haven't checked into it again though.

Comment: thanks for responding its really nice idea you control your recording from a window which is in desktop, but in actual recording output it will be shown invisible.yet i did't get any idea but still searching

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to exclude specific windows from OS X's built-in display recording APIs:

- AVFoundation's AVCaptureScreenInput  (10.7+)
- Core Graphics CGDisplayStream (10.8+)

Both above methods seem to grab the screen content *after* compositing, when the final screen output has already been composited together.
So excluding your recording window would require you to use an API that allows you to composite the windows yourself and later append those custom frames to an AVAssetWriterInput.

[Quartz Window Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference) allow you to take snapshots of single windows via CGWindowListCreateImage.  A good sample project that also shows how to composite multiple window shots together is [Son of Grab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html).

After retrieving the stitched together shot, you'd have to append it to an AVAssetWriterInput. AVFoundation provides a convenience class to append custom pixel buffers to a movie: [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Especially the AVFoundation part could become very frustrating and you might run into performance problems as the compositing is very likely to be slower than OS X's built-in compositor, but overall it should be possible to to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks weichsel. I had pretty much come to the same conclusion of using CGWindowListCreateImage but wanted to be sure before proceeding. Thanks for the extra tips about the AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. Might have taken me a bit longer to find that. Do you know of any method to see how AVCaptureScreenInput itself is implemented? Is it a valid idea to think about subclassing it and somewhat modifying it to do what I need?

Comment: I don't know what AVFoundation uses to record the screen. But probably CGDisplayStream as it's lower level and it provides similar options (capture cursor, min frame duration, …).   
To learn more about CGDisplayStream, you can look into the comments in CGDisplayStream.h (no real docs available yet).

This also could be interesting - A thread about excluding NSWindows from screenshots: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/326518-turning-off-screen-shot-ability.html 
It doesn't offer a viable solution though.

Comment: Hadn't seen CGDisplayStream. Will take a deeper look at it. Yeah, I ran into the NSWindows discussion too. Sadly, it doesn't work or I wasn't able to get it to work. Thanks again for the response!

Comment: The NSWindow category mentioned in one of the last posts works for me (https://github.com/heardrwt/RHAdditions/blob/master/RHAdditions/NSWindow%2BRHPreventCaptureAdditions.m), but I think doesn't solve your problem as it doesn't "hide" the window but draw it's content area with a checkerboard pattern instead. (Apart from that it uses private API calls)

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with implementing functionality like this? It's been a while and I know that Zoom screen sharing and Slack screen sharing is able to do this. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [ScreenCaptureKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit) is now able to do that